# How print and image with react map function

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs

My web app will open a array of JSON with map function, i need when the react the an "" the image get write on the table and the link on the image still active, my function is:

```
                <table className="table">
                    <thead className=".thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.contatos.map((contato, index) => (<>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{contato.id}</td>
                                <td>{contato.nome}</td>
                                <td>{contato.telefone}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </>))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

this is my sql db

```
INSERT INTO contatos(nome,telefone) VALUES ('<a><img src="example.com"</img></a>','305-565');
INSERT INTO contatos(nome,telefone) VALUES ('Carey Shers','305-565');
INSERT INTO contatos(nome,telefone) VALUES ('Bill Manys','298-2125');
INSERT INTO contatos(nome,telefone) VALUES ('john peter','465-1827');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd want to store names and image urls in different columns in a db and work in a way that if name exists - show name, else, show image.
Assuming that is something that can not be changed, you can just use react's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property to set the name. So it wouldn't matter if it's a name or an image as the code would work for both the scenarios.

**so you'd replace**

- `<td>{contato.nome}</td>`

with -

- `<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contato.nome }} />`

Also, whenever you're using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, make sure that the data that is coming from the DB is safe. Else your website can be prone to XSS attacks.

Comment: thanks, i will put other rows in my code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).